# Is there a way to restrict PRs from a specific branch to another in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, branch, branching-and-merging, policy

I'm trying to find a way to restrict a PR creation from something starting with `feature/xxxx` to `release/xxxxx` ( or in a simpler way, from `feature` branch to `release` branch) in **Azure DevOps**. A workaround might be filtering the path in build validation of branch policy as mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/azuredevops/comments/fgbhym/prevent_some_branches_to_create_pull_request/), but it needs a build pipeline for this. Is there any other way that this can be done? I know about these two predefined variables in Azure DevOps: `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch`, `System.PullRequest.SourceBranch` but then again these are only [available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for yaml pipeline. I'm pretty new with this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no permission to restrict PRs. The only way is set [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops) to protect target branch. You can use the workaround you mentioned, or you could add required reviewer for the affected path:

[image]